# How to add 5 stars rating as default?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make 5 stars the default option in the Woocommerce rating system, so when a user is going to leave a review he doesn't have to manually select the five stars option.

I've tried the solution outlined here, but it didn't work:

https://pastebin.com/f0at8QaF

```
add_filter('site-reviews/config/forms/review-form', function ($fields) {
if (isset($fields['rating'])) {
    $fields['rating']['value'] = 5;
}
return $fields;
```

});

I'm using a theme I purchased that changed a few things, so maybe that's the problem; but any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One simple idea is to use JQuery to select 5-stars reviews. You need to write your jquery script and call it in your functions.php file. Check below how this works for me.

1)This is an example of how your jQuery script (in wp-content/themes/your-theme/your-script.js) might look:
*you may need to locate and change the classes in your theme that refer to stars

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.stars').addClass('selected');
$('.star-5').addClass('active');
})
})(jQuery);
```

2)And this is an example of how you call your script at your theme's functions.php file.

```
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'fullreciew', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery_test.js', // this is the location of your script file
        array('jquery') 
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_my_script' );
```

Tested at https://themeforest.net/item/flatsome-multipurpose-responsive-woocommerce-theme/5484319 and it works